# Redisson RedisExecutor too many calls causing high CPU load

Tags: java, caching, redisson

I'm usign Java Redisson client version 3.16.0 and java version 1.8

below is my cache config `ttl`

```
{
  "cache1": {
    "ttl": 12000000
  },
  "cache2": {
    "ttl": 12000000
  },
  "cache3": {
    "ttl": 12000000
  }
}
```

I can see that there many calls using `RedisExecutor` which causing **high CPU utilization** even the TTL is very high around 6 hours, however the `RedisExecutor` keep calling redis doing many commands to evict the cache and it runs every seconds even if there is no traffic on the application

```
1- RedisExecutor- connection released for command (EVAL) and params [if redis.call('setnx', KEYS[6]

2- RedisExecutor- acquired connection for command (EVAL) and params [if redis.call('setnx', KEYS[6], ARGV[4]) ==
```

any recommendation to reduce number if these calls to maintain the CPU usage ?

Comment: Heap memory usage? What is the CPU being used for?

Comment: Sorry @aled, I'm not getting your point , do you mean its a Heap memory issue ?

Comment: There are many possible causes for high CPU in Java applications. Static analysis of code is most of the time useless by itself. Information about the dynamic state of the running application is needed. What analysis have you realized so far?